# PHP (Regex) code to remove a Div with a specific ID

Tags: php, regex, html, tags

How can I get rid of these in a scrapped page using a PHP Regex code to go over the content and replace it with nothing?

```
<div id="news-id-245245" style="display:inline;">
```

I also do not have any other parts of the page where I use an ID for a div, so it will also work if a pattern simply removed all DIVs with an ID tag.

The id of the div is always as follows: "news-id-NUMBER"

Comment: Looks like I got it to work, I am not sure if this even makes sense but I did mnanage to get rid of suck Divs

    $content = preg_replace('/<div id="news-id-(.*?)" style="display:inline;">/s', '', $content);

Comment: For managing HTML documents you may also give DOMElements ( http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) a try. It will certainly add more code to your project but it will give you more control over the document.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your comment "*I am not sure if this even makes sense*": Since it works, it makes sense. I simplified your solution a bit; we don't need the parentheses around `.*?`. (We do need the `?` unless there is only a single match in `$content`.)

```
$content = preg_replace('/<div id="news-id-.*?" style="display:inline;">/s', '', $content);
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't think RegEx is an option here, you'll have to call it specifically. For example:

```
<?php
   echo "<style>#news-id-NUMBER{display:none;}</style>";
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. NUMBER is a random number which I cannot know beforehand, so I need a pattern to remove ALL numbers if I am to use your answer but it seems very useful I'd rather get it to work rather than go over the content and remove the DIVs.

Wouldn't something like this work?
    preg_replace('/<div[^>]+id="'.preg_quote($id, '/').'"[^>]*>(.*?)<\/div>/s', '', $result[1]);